# react BrowserRouter resulting in "You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mdbootstrap, mdbreact

I am hitting this problem constantly, and have been stuck at it for a long time now. I am new to `mbdreact` library and I have been trying this example of theirs from this [link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/navigation/compositions/). This has given me too many problems in debugging and understanding what is going on.

**Problem :**

```
You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

The detailed error trace I could pull is as follows :

```
Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
    at invariant (browser.js:34)
    at Route.computeMatch (Route.js:96)
    at new Route (Route.js:72)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:13082)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14978)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15845)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18879)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:18920)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18127)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19038)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:19941)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:19851)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:19825)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:19680)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19487)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:20191)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:20217)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:20285)
    at ReactRoot.push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:20564)
    at react-dom.development.js:20718
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:20068)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:20714)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:20781)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (index.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

**Code :**

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "contentful": "^7.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.8.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
//serviceWorker.unregister();
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { MDBContainer } from 'mdbreact';

import FixedNavbarExample from './components/navbar/NavbarPage'



const App = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <FixedNavbarExample/>
            <MDBContainer style={{height: 100}} className="text-center mt-5 pt-5">
            </MDBContainer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

`NavbarPage.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { MDBContainer, MDBNavbar, MDBNavbarBrand, MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavbarToggler, MDBCollapse, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink, MDBIcon } from 'mdbreact';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class FixedNavbarExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collapse: false,
        };
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({
            collapse: !this.state.collapse,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const bgPink = {backgroundColor: '#e91e63'}
        const container = {height: 1300}
        return(
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <header>
                        <MDBNavbar style={bgPink} dark expand="md" scrolling fixed="top">
                            <MDBNavbarBrand href="/">
                                <strong>Navbar</strong>
                            </MDBNavbarBrand>
                            <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={ this.onClick } />
                            <MDBCollapse isOpen = { this.state.collapse } navbar>
                                <MDBNavbarNav left>
                                    <MDBNavItem active>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#">Home</MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#">Features</MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#">Pricing</MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#">Options</MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                </MDBNavbarNav>
                                <MDBNavbarNav right>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon icon="facebook" /></MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon icon="twitter" /></MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                    <MDBNavItem>
                                        <MDBNavLink to="#"><MDBIcon icon="instagram" /></MDBNavLink>
                                    </MDBNavItem>
                                </MDBNavbarNav>
                            </MDBCollapse>
                        </MDBNavbar>
                    </header>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FixedNavbarExample;
```

**What I have found so far :**

- I have referenced the following StackOverflow posts

  - [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314541/you-should-not-use-route-or-withrouter-outside-a-router-when-using-react-route)
  - [link2](https://github.com/udilia/learn-react-by-building-a-web-app/issues/3)
- from what I am seeing the problem is in the `NavbarPage.js`. The articles above tell me 2 things : (First-Thing) to wrap all of the content in `<div>` which the example link from `mdbreact` tutorial is already doing & (Second-Thing) to move  inside  which is also done.
- I have also tried renaming the import from `BrowserRouter as Router` to just `BrowserRouter`, and made corresponding refactoring. Even that resulted in the same error.

Looking for help in understanding what is causing this problem, to further my understanding in `react`, `mdbreact`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your react-router-dom version (beta.6) is incompatible with mdbreact library.
If you install stable version ^4.3.1 everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Rotarepmi, hopefully this will fix the problem. Going to give this a try quickly.

Comment: thanks a ton ! I noticed you are part of the `mdbreact` team from github issues you help answer. Would it be possible for your team to maintain a compatibility table of some sort?

Comment: If you already have one, I definitely might have missed it. If you could point me to it - that will be great.

Comment: Here is such table: https://mdbootstrap.com/general/browsers-and-devices/

But I suppose it doesn't fullfill your needs? :)

MDBReact package is continuosly updated, so it is compatible with all newest Stable versions (or at least backward compatible). You've been using beta version of react-router-dom, which caused the problem.

Comment: You can see all the mdbreact dependencies (and their versions) in `dependencies` here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdbreact

Answer (score 0):

Another case of the same Error is due to the fact that in main App components you have missing BrowserRouter tag. Let me give an example:

```
<ApolloProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
      .....
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      .....
  </BrowserRouter>
</ApolloProvider>
```

Note the surrounding tag.