# Duplicate ReactJS import issue when using npm link to test component before publishing as npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a simple component like this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function MyComponentWithState(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    return (
        <p>My value is: {value}</p>
    ) 
}

export default MyComponentWithState;
```

and I want to publish it on NPM as a separate package. so, to do that I prepared **package.json** and **webpack.config.js** like below.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "try-to-publish",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Just a test",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Behnam Azimi"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.39.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.8",
    "webpack-external-react": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.json:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
            'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dom'),
        }
    },
    externals: {
        'react': "commonjs react",
        'react-dom': "commonjs react-dom"
    },
};
```

and here is my **.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

These configs work like charm when I publish my component to NPM and install it in my another ReactJs project with `npm install , but my point is the local test!

I want to test this component/lib before publish. To do this I use `npm link` feature to link my component with my main ReactJS project.

As you saw above, my component is functional and I used hooks too. So when I inject the locally linked lib to my main ReactJs project face this error,

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

My issue is related to the 3td reason. My project uses ReactJs and import it once and also my component will import React! I mean *twice React import in one project!*.

I also have **externals** config about `react` and `react-dom` in my Webpack config.

What should I do to solve that? Where is my mistake?

**Update:**
I also tried what @sung-m-kim and @eddie-cooro say but it not worked! Mean, I change the package.json and removed `react` and `react-dom` from `dependencies` and add them to `devDpendencies`.

Comment: FYI - I've deleted my answer as it hasn't worked 

Comment: What's the result of ```npm ls react```?

Comment: @FatemeFazli, `-- UNMET DEPENDENCY react@16.9.0`, This is the result of `npm ls react`

Comment: @FatemeFazli, I changed some and I faced `-- react@16.9.0` as `npm ls react` result

Comment: It seems you have 2 reacts, works when you publish package to NPM and then import it directly from NPM. but doesn't work when locally linked. fot testing your package locally you can use [npm-link-shared](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-link-shared) to prevent duplicate react error.

Comment: @FatemeFazli, `...ignored due to missing or erroneous package.json`. Not worked!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue. I used **RollupJS** instead of **Webpack** for bundling as bundle tool.

Here is my **rollup.config.js**:

```
import {uglify} from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'

export default {
    input: "./src/index.js",
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    output: {
        name: 'test-lib',
        format: "cjs",
    },
    plugins: [
        babel({
            exclude: "node_modules/**"
        }),
        uglify(),
    ],
};
```

and my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "test-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/test-lib.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c -o dist/test-lib.min.js"
  },
  "author": "Behnam Azimi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup": "^1.21.4",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.3"
  }
}
```

After these changes, `npm link` worked truly in my **ReactJS (Hooks)** project.

Notice that it's just a simple Rollup config to show my solution and you can add many kinds of stuff like hot reloading, styles loaders, and many other plugins to the config.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in combination with Lerna

Answer (score 9):

I finally solved this problem by these steps.

run **npm link** inside

`<your-library-package>/node_modules/react`

also

run **npm link** inside

`<your-library-package>/node_modules/react-dom`

then run **npm link react** and **npm link react-dom** inside your **application root directory**

and dont forget to keep react and react-dom as externals in the library

```
// webpack.config.js

const externals = {
    "react": "react",
    "react-dom": "react-dom",
}

module.exports = {
    .
    .
    .

   externals
   }
```

Comment: You can also run the following from the directory you're trying to link the library to `npm link ../library-package-dir/node_modules/react ../library-package-dir/node_modules/react-dom ../library-package-dir`

Answer (score 3):

Set the `react` and `react-native` packages only inside of the `peerDependencies` part of package.json, not the `dependencies`. Also for local development (When your package is not included in any other react projects and you want to to run it locally), you can use the `devDependencies` field.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem in a typescript react project.

probably,  when use the `npm link` use the `react` from main app project and the component project.

So, in your `package.json` remove `react` from `dependencies` and/or `devDependencies`

Check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807950/5183591

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue.
In my case, I developed some UI components as a package, and inside that I have an example folder with the React app which Create React App.

The issue is when I install the package into an example app using `npm i ../` it installs all the files in the package to the example app including the node_modules folder. Since I have installed the `react` and `react-dom` as peer dependencies, the example app now has two different react copies.

Removing the node_module folder from the package and re-installing the package again fixed my issue.